# How do semantic text comparison APIs work

Tags: nlp

I am currently doing a project where we are trying to gauge explanatory answers submitted by users against a correct answer. I have come across APIs like [dandelion](https://dandelion.eu/) and [paralleldots](https://www.paralleldots.com/semantic-analysis), both of which are capable of checking how close 2 texts are to each other semantically.

These APIs are giving me favorable responses for questions like:

> What is the distinction between debtor and creditor?
>
> Answer1: A debtor is a person or enterprise that owes money to another
> party.  A creditor is a person, bank, or other enterprise that has
> lent money or extended credit to another  party.
>
> Answer2: A debtor has a debt or legal obligation to pay an amount to
> another person or entity,  from whom goods were purchased or services
> were obtained.  A creditor may be a bank, supplier

Dandelion gave me a score of 81% and paralleldots gave me 4.8/5 for the same answer. This is quite expected.

However, before I prepare a demo and plan to eventually use them in production, I am interested in understanding to some extent how these APIs are generating these scores.

Is it a tf-idf based vector product of the stemmed POSses??

PS: Not an expert in NLP

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad: semantic sentence similarity is an open issue in NLP and there are a variety of ways of performing this task, all of them being far from perfect at the current stage. As an example, just consider that:

> Trump is the president of the United States

and

> Trump has never been the president of the United States

have a semantic similarity of 5 according to paralleldots. Now, according to your definition of similarity this may be ok or not, but the point is that according to what you have to do with this similarity it may not be fully suitable if you have specific requirements.

Anyway, as for the implementation, there's no single "standard" way of performing this and there's a pletora of features that can be used: tf-idf (or equivalent), syntactic structure of the sentence (i.e. constituency or dependency parse tree), mention of entities extracted from the text, etc... or, following the latest trends, a deep neural network which doesn't need any explicit feature.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Fiddling around on my own I was also getting high coherence scores for seemingly incoherent statements on these APIs. I observed if my answer has ample keywords (present in the sample answer), but a different meaning the APIs fail.
In your experience have you come across APIs which can do  a more efficient semantic text comparison?
My use case is very similar to the example given in the question. Simple questions to check concepts through short descriptive answer questions in the domain of Finance, Technology, Sales etc.

Comment: I don't know any APIs that are more reliable than this (but I don't know many APIs like this in general); I guess this is pretty much the state of the art. Probably the best solution is to try out different APIs and see which one best suits your data or develop something yourself (but this is hard, time-consuming and not guaranteed to bring better results)